# Why a double is negative when it ought be positive?

Tags: c++, types

I want to create an application that generates full list of phone numbers that satisfies equatation:

[image: Equatation]

`x` is a rational number.

We can assume that

[image: x=s/t]

Now, after some transformations, we obtain

[image: Equatation]

As `telephone number` is integer and `10^9` is integer, we know that `t * 666333999 / s` is integer. Therefore `s` is a divisor of `t * 666333999`

As yet, my programm searches for all divisors of 666333999. I thing it ought do it well (it should write most of the phone numbers). Unfortunately sometimes my phone number (it's the `tym` variable) is a negative number.

Why is it so?

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector < unsigned > divisor;
    const int number = 666333999;
    long double tym;                     // it's the phone number (9 digits)
    for (int i = 2; i < number + 1; i++) 
    {                              // I'm pushing all the divisors to vector.
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
        divisor.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    for(unsigned i = 1; i < divisor.size() + 1; i++) 
    {                                      // i are consecutives values of s
        for(unsigned j = 1; j < (unsigned)2000000000; j++) 
        {                                  // j are consecutives values of t
            tym = number / divisor[i];
            tym *= j;
            if(tym > 99999999 && tym < 2000000000)  // I must substract 10^9
            {
                 cout << "\t(!)\t i = " << i << " and j = " << j << ","
                         "div[i] = " << divisor[i] << ", telephone"
                         " number = " << (tym - 1000000000) << endl;
            }
            else if(tym >= 2000000000)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It overflows. Add a check for negative values?

Comment: I would avoid floating point arithmetic for this exercise, and use 64-bit integers.  A 32-bit integer will not hold the full range of 9 bit numbers, but 64-bit will.

Comment: Also, you should consider using the concept of Greatest Common Divisor (GCD).  There are very efficient algorithms for computing it, and Google will help you find them.

Comment: @JoeZ I was starting to lean towards floating point mathematics.   You beat me to it.

Comment: @JoeZ, a `double` will hold any 53-bit integer without loss. I doubt that's the source of the problem. However that big `int` constant might be it.

Comment: Why are you specifying the constraint in such a terribly obtuse way?

Comment: @KerrekSB Why obtuse?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - the check is in line `if(tym > 99999999 && tym < 2000000000)  // I must substract 10^9`

Comment: @enedil: Because you're essentially expressing something like "x > 3" as "(20 - x) * 5 - 100 < -15 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1", which is silly. Simplify first, then present the simplest form of the constraint.

Comment: @MarkRansom : I've used platforms that implement divide in a way that can be inaccurate in the LSB of the mantissa, so I generally prefer to implement exact integer algorithms with integers throughout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number involved in your calculation exceed the capability of a 32 bit integer but may fit the 64 bit integers.

May be in your platform `int` is 32 bit. Just use `long long`.

If you want to be sure about the 64 bit, use `std::int64_t`, defined in `<cstdint>`